# Change checkbox state according to its value in generated table

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the code where i generating my table :

```
foreach($list_user as $temp){
        $this->table->add_row(++$i,
        $temp->ID_user,
        $temp->nama,            
        $temp->email,
        form_checkbox('selected[]', $temp->active),
        anchor('user/update/'.$temp->ID_user, 'update', array('class'=>'update')).' '.
        anchor('user/delete/'.$temp->ID_user, 'delete', array('class'=>'delete', 
        'onclick' => "return confirm('Apa Anda yakin mau menghapus data user $temp->nama?')"))
        );
    }
```

Now if i generate the `$temp->active` without checkbox it will give me the right value like 1 (active) or 0 (not active)
My question is : How to change the value of my checkbox so if the value is 1 it will be automatically checked and vice versa.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the third parameter of the `form_checkbox()` which is boolean:

```
form_checkbox('selected[]', $temp->active, $temp->active)
```

Answer (score 1):

The form_checkbox() function has following parameters:

```
form_checkbox('nameofcheckbox', 'value', BOOL);
```

so the code

```
form_checkbox('selected[]', '123', $temp->active);
```

would produce

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="123" checked="checked" />
```

if the `$temp->active` value was 1